# How to deal with relative paths in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony

It seems like you get different relative paths depending on how you are executing the script: console or web.

I find this extremely annoying, haven't you had any issues with this?

Every time I need to copy/move/delete files, I have to be thinking if I'm on cli or web, if I saved it as cli or web path, etc.

Eg: Say someone uploads an image. You will probably store the image with this kind of path: `uploads/picture-123.jpeg`. Then a cronjob decides to move the picture or something. First it will have to preppend this to the source path: `web/`. It will also need a target path, that begins with `web/`. After moving it, it will want to save the new path in the corresponding database row or document, so it will have to strip `web/` from the target path.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For handling files the best practice for paths defining is to use absolute ones, that start from `%kernel.root_dir%`:

```
parameters:
    your_upload_path: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/
```