# How to dynamically validate form field in symfony 2.3

Tags: validation, symfony

I need to validate input field depending on options i pass to buildForm()
And i have this code i glued together from googling around.
However in controller

`$form->isValid()`

passes with values that are outside the range:

```
$builder->add('limit', 'integer', array(
    'constraints' => [
        new Assert\Range(array(
            'min' => $options['min'],
            'max' => $options['max'],
            'minMessage' => 'min error message',
            'maxMessage' => 'max error message',
        ))
    ],
));
```

How do I dynamically validate the input?

**UPDATE**:

[Symfony2 validation using Assert annotation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883128/symfony2-validation-using-assert-annotation-does-not-work) same issue. Will have to write a custom validator.

Comment: define dynamically, do you mean the min/max changes depending on form content or the min/max can change depending on the data used to build the form?

Comment: depending on data used to build the form

Answer (score 0):

You can do something basic like this:

```
if ($option['condition'] === 'whatever') {
    $limtiConstraint = new Assert\Range(array(
        'min'        => $options['min'],
        'max'        => $options['max'],
        'minMessage' => 'min error message',
        'maxMessage' => 'max error message',
    ));
} else {
    // $limtiConstraint = 'other constraint with other options'
}

$builder->add('limit', 'integer', array(
    'constraints' => [$limtiConstraint]
));
```

Or if you want to modify the limits, you can use the ternary operator:

```
'min' => $options['condition'] ? $options['min'] : $options['other_min'],
```

Comment: Is there no error in this construction ? `true ? $options['condition'] ? $options['min'] : $options['other_min']`